# Embedding images from Picasa in SO questions

Tags: support, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

How do I embed an image from my public picasa album into a Stack Overflow question? For example: [this image](http://picasaweb.google.co.uk/lh/photo/IxksxmBh360sZqW9ZIhRpQ?feat=directlink)?

It shows up as:

[http://picasaweb.google.co.uk/lh/photo/IxksxmBh360sZqW9ZIhRpQ?feat=directlink http://picasaweb.google.co.uk/lh/photo/IxksxmBh360sZqW9ZIhRpQ?feat=directlink](http://picasaweb.google.co.uk/lh/photo/IxksxmBh360sZqW9ZIhRpQ?feat=directlink)

when I try to embed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the wrong url: http://lh3.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw5aVZJfG1I/AAAAAAAAGkI/6jYnsB91HjI/image_thumb[1](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw5aVZJfG1I/AAAAAAAAGkI/6jYnsB91HjI/image_thumb[1].png).png

Right-click on the image you see with your link and "copy url".
[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw5aVZJfG1I/AAAAAAAAGkI/6jYnsB91HjI/image_thumb[1].png](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw5aVZJfG1I/AAAAAAAAGkI/6jYnsB91HjI/image_thumb[1].png)

Comment: Yea, jldupont is right. You have to embed the image's url, not the url of the page that contains the image.