# How to place an image in a Stack Overflow question

Tags: support, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

I am a new developer to Android. Whenever I used to have some question I would be asking on Stack Overflow and would be getting most of the solutions there. Some of the users asked me to upload an screenshot for my query. How do I insert the screenshots for my queries?

Comment: Above the editor, there's an orange button with a question mark that goes here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I think you should ask questions about how to use SO on the meta site. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 5):

First you should realise, you need at least **10** reputation points to be able to use images in your post. You can check the [accompanying reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user), which also explains how to use images in your post at the bottom.

From that page:

> #### How do I add images and links to my posts?
>
> We use Markdown to format posts, so there are a variety of ways of adding links:
>
> - bare urls `http://example.com`
> - HTML `<a href="http://example.com">example link</a>`
> - Markdown `[example link](http://example.com)`
> - the editor toolbar button insert link toolbar button [image: Icon]
>
> Images can be added similarly:
>
> - HTML `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`
> - Markdown `![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)`
> - the editor toolbar button insert image toolbar button [image: Icon]

Just to give you some graphical aid, which I always love:

[image: Click there]

Comment: But how do you crop an image you added?

Answer (score 1):

There is a button for uploading images in the WYSIWYG editor. It's the 6<sup>th</sup> one from the left.

Comment: But if I want to crop that image in stackoverflow  itself than How i'll do it?