# Is there an image number limit in questions from new users?

Tags: discussion, privileges, images

I have seen a number of questions from new users where someone has requested pictures/screenshots and the new user responds to say that they are not allowed to add additional images (i.e. permissions don't allow it).

In the privilege [Remove New User Restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) it says that:

> New users cannot:
>
> - post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile

However, it's not clear if that includes images, particularly using the *Image* button on the toolbar.

In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question/83099#83099) to *[How to place an image in a Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question)* it says

> First you should realise, you need at least 10 reputation points to be able to use images in your post. You can check the [accompanying reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user), which also explains how to use images in your post at the bottom.

and

> Images can be added similarly:
>
> - HTML `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`
> - Markdown `![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)`
> - the editor toolbar button insert image toolbar button Icon

But that page no longer has the section regarding images.

What restrictions are there on the number of images that new users can add to their question?

Comment: Related: [Which SE sites require 10 reputation points to post images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258875/335251)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's currently no limit to the number of images *if* you can post images at all.

On some sites (like Stack Overflow), new users are prohibited from posting *any* images; if you upload an image it won't be embedded in the post; instead, a link to it will be inserted. And this link counts toward the two-link maximum.

Note that the default format used by the image uploader also hyperlinks the image to the image source, meaning as a new user you'll be *effectively* limited to two images *even on [sites that allow images from new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111388/new-users-and-attaching-images)* unless you manually create your image links (or remove those hyperlinks).

[image: You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links]