# Embed image in Stack Exchange

Tags: support, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Is there a way to embed an image (screen shot, for example) in a Stack Exchange question by just supplying the image (from my computer)?  Otherwise, I need to FTP the image to a server and then use that image URL.

Comment: Yes there is. You just click on the image button.

Comment: Hmm.  Seems the formatting help might mention that.  (I never even saw that bar of icons).  The question mark takes me to the markdown page, which explains how to link to an image.  So that's what I did.  Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, just click the image button above the editor  (it is just right of the **`{}`** button).

[image: Image Embed]

<kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> is the shortcut for it and you will see,

[image: Paste From ClipBoard, Link or Upload one]

Comment: Does not work in the Stack Exchange app for iOS. That widget only lets you pick an image from the device’s camera or past photos.

Comment: @BasilBourque - this question (and answer) predate the iOS app by quite a bit. The question is for the website, not the app, as is the answer.

Comment: I understand. Just helping other readers who might land here from the first hit on a Google search. Not a criticism.

Comment: I hope that, someday, the grey and white visual art used for the "insert picture" button on stack exchange will be available as a cellphones emoticon (or emoji) for use on android cellphones. I would do it myself, but nobody has yet taught me how to make a library of cellphones emoticons and make it available for anyone with internet access and an android brand cellphone to use. I want to make some of my own emojis. I am good at using GIMP, but I don't know how to transform the jpeg images into a library which can be selected from and embedded into cellphone text-based messages.