# How can I add a diagram to a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, images

I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow and to clearly demonstrate my situation I need to include a very simple diagram. How can I do that? I've tried diagrams created on MS Word inserting shapes, but it didn't show up :(

Comment: "but it..." What happened to the rest of your question?

Comment: @Cody Gray: It was in a diagram.

Comment: @Piskvor: very funny, guys. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a button on your keyboard called "Print Screen", and you can paste it to Microsoft Paint, then upload it following [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post/75498#75498)

Comment: and ALT-PrintScreen to get the active window only

Comment: But: always remember that search and accessibility are important too. Search engines and screen readers need something more than just an image.

Comment: thanks YOU a LOT :) 1 upvote for introducing me with the AMAZING "Print Screen" functionality :D...tried, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 6):

Taking a screen shot and uploading it as @YOU says is usually the way to go; To add another possibility, in some cases, uploading an empty image and drawing directly in here using George Edison's brilliant [freehand drawing userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor-now-supported-on-every-st) is also an option - *if* the illstration doesn't require too much text.

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1168427294.png

Comment: Support for text is planned :)

Comment: thanks Pekka for the info plug-in :)