# Would adding one font colour help?

Tags: feature-request, information-display, fonts

An excessive palette of colours distracts, as per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115457/226001). However, what of adding simply one more colour?

1 key reason: Suppose you're quoting a long text that already uses bolds and italics. Then all formatting tools have been exhausted; no tools remain. So how can you  highlight something?

The following posts already use or substantiate the utility of one more  colour:

- [Is there a way to change the color of text in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92722/226001)
- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/209560/50720
- [Adding feature to colour the text](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/436), was broached for French SE.
- I cite a supportive comment from moderator 'snailboat' below:

  > For Japanese, where italics aren't often used and look strange, it would give us something other than bold to use. (The Powers That Be have already forbidden underlining, which would also be very useful on language sites.)

Comment: I don't understand the relevance to language sites.   Why would **language sites** benefit significantly from having 1 color?

Comment: For Japanese, where italics aren't often used and look strange, it would give us something other than bold to use.  (The Powers That Be have already forbidden underlining, which would also be very useful on language sites.)

Comment: @snailboat Thank you for your support.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Since colour is needed to differentiate and highlight?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I still don't see what makes language sites special in this regard.  Why do language sites need this special treatment where regular sites do not?

Comment: You may want to consider adding the info from @snailboat 's comment to your question, so that the reason this feature is needed is a little more clear.

Comment: @apaul34208 Thanks. Done.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Some regular sites are treated specially, like those with MathJAX? Please see my updated OP.

Comment: Another answer that benefits from colours: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/5043/50720