# How can I add a screen shot into my question?

Tags: support, images, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I post a screenshot on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow)
>   [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155556)

I have seen some people post screen shots.

How can I add one of these to my question?

Comment: Don't delete the automatically added duplicate links

Comment: @simchona one of them was incorrect. and I added a correct FAQ duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Ubuntu or other Gnome based OS (just like I do) you can just

1. press <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> key (usually, on the right top side of the keyboard).
   Alternatively, you can use `gnome-screenshot` command in console.
2. choose where you want to save it (on latest versions it automatically saves picture to Pictures in your home directory).
3. then, in your post press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> or click this icon to add that image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**However you want to**

I use Windows 7's Snipping Tool.
[image: snipped snipping tool]

But there are many many others