# Policy on externally linking to answers

Tags: discussion, answers, external-project

As part of a project I'll be requiring a wide range of people to send me screenshots of an application I'm developing.  I would like very much to link to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) and more specifically Andrew Thompson's answer to it.

I'm not sure how acceptable that is though?  While I don't think it'll create a huge amount of traffic or anything, it feels a little weird to be using SE, and specifically someone else's words on SE, as an instruction manual.

I was wondering if there was any policy, best practice or etiquette around this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Linking is a pretty big part of The Internet.

In fact, I'm gonna go out on a limb and say if you aren't linking to things you're not *really* using The Internet.

So... Link away. I'm pretty sure our servers can handle it.

Thanks for the polite check though!

P.S. Probably worth noting that the answer you want to link to is a wiki, maintained for the benefit of folks using this site. While it's very unlikely to change suddenly and tragically without notice, there's always that possibility - so, y'know, be aware. As JoshC mentions, you're free to make a copy of the answer instead if you prefer, as long as you [attribute it to the authors](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: Yep. That's the reason for SO. It's a [CC-Wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).