# Uploading images that are too large

Tags: support, images, uploader

I'm trying to upload some photos from my phone that exceed the size cap on the upload function--I'm getting this error message:

> Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB)

I expected SE to do some automatic compression, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post/99735#99735) (perhaps it's outdated?):

> Images that are too large will be scaled down by the SE software...

But it doesn't seem to be doing so.

How can I add such photos to my post? Compression? Reset photo size on camera? Upload somewhere public? I know these are all possible, but I'm wondering what's the easiest and if there's something SE has to offer that I haven't covered.

Comment: The "Images that are too large will be scaled down" refers to images you try to upload by URL as far as I can tell. The 2MB limit is for the raw request itself.

Comment: This occurred when trying to upload a file from my computer.

Comment: As a work around, you can upload it first to imgur.com then upload to the post by choosing "You can also provide a link from the web".

Comment: I don't think I have an imgur account. for now, I ended up opening everything in kolourpaint and scaling it down 50%. kind of a pain though.

Comment: You don't need account to upload images on imgur. Also, Windows 7 ships with built in image resizer.

Comment: I'm on Linux ;-)

Comment: This is *really* inconvenient considering my *phone* generally doesn't create useful images in under 3.5MB!  Are there any plans to fix this annoying bug or do I need to burn my phone to the ground?

Comment: Just a note if anybody finds this (like me again), if you are trying to resize a Google Photo to upload to SE, instead of downloading it, right click and view the image (as previewed when you double click on it) in a new tab.  That image will be smaller and you can save it to upload.

Comment: Related feature request: [When copy-pasting images from the clipboard, automatically reduce image size to below the 2 MB requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330122/335251)

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262264/uploading-images-that-are-too-large#comment855348_262264), if your image is over 2 MB, you can upload it directly to image sharing websites, then include a link in your post.

Here's a detailed explanation of the steps if you're unsure how to do so:

**PC option - Using Imgur:**
<sub><sup>***Note: It is difficult to upload to imgur quickly on a smartphone (unless you want to install their app)***</sup></sub>

- Go to https://imgur.com/upload <sub><sup>*(Only works on a PC, not a smartphone)*</sup></sub>
- Drag your image into the page, or click Choose Photo/Video to look up its location on your device.  You could also [paste](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-copy-and-paste/) the image onto the page.
- Wait for it to upload.  There may be an advertisement you have to wait for\close.  And very large images may take a while as well.  If so you may see an uploading window like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47GLd.jpg).
- [Copy](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-copy-and-paste/) the link.  You can just select and copy the page address at the top, and it'll give a smaller version.  Or you should be able to get a link directly to the image by moving your mouse over the image and selecting the [copy link button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNJBy.jpg) that pops up.
- [Paste](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-copy-and-paste/) it into your StackExchange post and rejoice!

You can upload up to 20 MB images, as well as animated GIFS\videos up to 200 MB.

**Smartphone option (or for any device) - PostImages:**

- Go to https://postimages.org
- Drag your image into the page, or click Choose Image (if prompted for an action on Android choose My Files to be able to navigate to your file)
- Copy the **[direct link](https://i.postimg.cc/nhLP37wy/image.png)**.  On smartphones you may need to scroll down below the image to find this link.  You can use the copy button on the right of the address, or [select and copy](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-copy-and-paste/) it yourself.
- [Paste](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-copy-and-paste/) the link into your StackExchange post and rejoice!

PostImages max image size is 24 Mb, which should be plenty for almost all images, other than the most extreme resolutions of smartphone or DSLR cameras.

**Other options:**

- Sites like **[Imgbb](https://imgbb.com)**, **[ImgBox](https://imgbox.com)**, or **[ImgPile](https://imgpile.com)**
- Find additional alternatives from a list site like [AlternativesTo](https://alternativeto.net/software/postimage-org/) or [search Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=image%20sharing%20website)

Hopefully this helps users lacking experience to upload images in their posts and improve site usage.

Comment: Or just crop your screenshot. You rarely need the entire screen to illustrate a point.

Comment: iPhones allow you to choose the size of photo at the time of choosing one from your photo gallery - large or medium suit most cases for me.

Comment: Also note you can actually put the image into the actual text of your post using [the code from this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253406/3038828) (fill in the src with your image link)... but if you find that too difficult, just pasting the link will often suffice, and other users just may embed it later if they think it useful.