# When copy-pasting images from the clipboard, automatically reduce image size to below the 2 MB requirement

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

The copy-paste feature is great (and I think was only implemented recently).

I wonder though if it could be further improved by also automatically reducing the size of the image if the image is above the 2 MB requirement? That would be even better.

Right now for images on my clipboard that are >2 MB, I have to paste the image somewhere else, save and reduce it, and then try again.

Comment: Sounds like a non-trivial optimization problem. Do attempts to upload images of over 2 MB in size happen often enough to warrant developer time on this? The image upload itself isn’t handled by Stack Exchange but by Imgur.

Comment: Very related: [Image size limit: Why it is set to 2 MB?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308507/image-size-limit-why-it-is-set-to-2-mb)

Comment: Related support question: [Uploading images that are too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262264/335251)

Comment: No ideas why this got 8 downvotes...

Answer (score 6):

That's not a trivial thing to do, because there are lots of considerations when shrinking an image.  Should the image be cropped?  Shrunk via quick point grabbing?  Shrunk by averaging several pixels together? (I can't think of the correct terms right now.)  The former can lose details, the later make the image fuzzy.  Maybe change the compression factor of a JPEG image, to make the file smaller but lose more of the image detail?  If it's a 256 color image, should we apply dithering as well?  Ultimately you're the one posting the image, and you'll have a better idea of what sort of resized image best represents your concept.

Comment: This question is a feature request. Certainly there are considerations that must be addressed, but other sites have this feature.  The fact that the photo loading feature does not handle it is discouraging for many potential posters on SE sites that often depend on photos.