# Enhance help on uploading images

Tags: feature-request, images, help-center, uploader

On sites where images are helpful to answer a question such as Gardening and Landscaping or Home Improvement new users regularly try and upload images that are greater than the 2 Mb image limit.  They get this message "Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB)."

If a user checks the help files with any of these search term: "photos", "photographs", "pictures: they will get no results. "Upload" has two results regarding chat rooms and markdown.  If there is no guidance for new users then the question is hard to answer or is abandoned.

I am asking for a new help topic called Photos and redirects from search so that if you search for photos, photographs, pictures, upload, image or images the new article is a search result.  The article should explain what the limits in size and format and how to reduce a picture in size so it can be uploaded.

[image: showing no search results in help]

Comment: something [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: @RobertLongson. Sort of, written for a non technical audience and with much more detail on how to reduce the size of a picture

Comment: Duplicate?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262264/282094 and somewhat similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317672/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262264/282094 deferred: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369424/282094

Comment: Adding to Rob's links: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273986/178179 
(PS: [the maximum image size one can upload is 2 MiB, not 2 MB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/178179))

Comment: @Rob Yes, I already made a feature request that is status deferred for automatic  image resizing but this feature request is about help files.  If the image limit issue is not going to be changed anytime soon then document it and provide guidance to the user on how to solve the problem