# How do I display image in a post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Does anybody know how to display a thumbnail or an image on a question or answer?

Not a link like this: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmuVz.png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

Comment: upvoted coz of the boom! haha chrs bro

Comment: I think this answer is no longer accurate, if it ever was.. the image uploaded by default provides a link to the image, which the op says he doesn't want. It doesn't give any detail on how to make the image thumbnail appear inline in the post - essentially it needs some advice like "put an exclamation mark at the start of the image link the uploaded inserts into your post"

Answer (score 11):

```
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmuVz.png)
```

[image]