# Do images uploaded to imgur.com have any backup?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur, backup

It seems that images uploaded on the SE sites are hosted on [imgur.com](http://www.imgur.com). Are these images stored somewhere else too? I mean, is there some sort of backup plan for restoring them? What happens if [imgur.com](http://www.imgur.com) goes bankrupt or something bad happens to it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We have a backup job, yes.  [Rebecca](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) wrote a backup program that runs daily IIRC, specifically backing up imgur just in case anything ever happens.

Comment: Nice! Think [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/152859) should be edited to reflect this?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - I'll let Rebecca do that, having written it she knows much more about how this works, I pinged her to take a look at this as well (:

Comment: what about the fact that unaccessed pictures are deleted? how do we ever get those back?

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @luchonacho had to replace stackoverflow with stackexchange, it's fixed now.

Comment: @Nick is this backup still running these days? (aka is this answer still relevant)

Comment: Yes and no. A totally different backup runs directly from the S3 buckets Imgur uses, but yes, we back it up to our systems daily in case anything were to happen.

Comment: Good to hear... any chance to edit the answer to reflect this? (Or it might be not really that important.)