# Inserting image in my questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Could anyone explain how to insert an image in my question?
I am not able to insert images. It will help me to ask a question easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sloved :  [Remove new user restrictions page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a new user, and you need to add an image, you can instead link to the image.

A user with edit ability is likely to add it to the post properly after checking it.

When this is the case, try not to link to over-sized images, which when added, may clutter up the post if it is too high.