# Recognize EXIF Orientation value when posting images (and/or allow transform in img tag)

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, images

I edited [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/how-to-estimate-price-of-an-old-crmo-frame) on Bicycles SE to convert the images from external links to  tags. The images contain an EXIF orientation attribute which is used to display the image appropriately as a link, but it is not respected when the image is displayed within SE.

Can SE implement the ability to read the image EXIF and use the Orientation to display the image correctly?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for EXIF orientation related findings

Answer (score 13):

If you include the image like you did with an `<img>` html tag the browser is responsible for fetching and displaying the image. Except for the url, the bytes making up the image never reach or pass any SE server (unless an [employee](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/833/nick-craver?tab=profile) decides to visit that question while doing maintenance on the server).

So there is not much SE can implement to fix that.

Fortunately you can achieve what you want by using the Stack Exchange [Image upload feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/158100) and then it turns out [imgur](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us) rotates the image for you...

#### uploaded to i.stack.imgur

[image: image in imgur]

#### for reference direct embedded with `<img>` tag

[image]

<sup>Your client (browser) may have decided to show this image also in its correct orientation. Thanks iOS/Mobile Safari for that. On IE11/Win7 of course the image is not on the right orientation (nor in Chrome/FF or Safari on Windows)</sup>

#### i.stack.imgur usage benefit

Uploading the image to imgur is a better option as well because those gets retained for ever while external hosted images might get deleted, making the question less useful, if not useless.

Comment: Ok, sorted it out. I can just use the SE upload widget and refer to the image by its URL. Quite easy, thanks for the info and example.

Comment: @rene it is funny that iOS shows both images correct. I guess they use the EXIF data already in their browser...

Answer (score 6):

Stack Exchange uses **[imgur](http://imgur.com/)** for uploading and hosting the images. Stack Exchange imgur's API *does* respect/recognize the EXIF data and auto-rotates the image to their correct *orientation* during the upload.

As per the the **Metapicz** (popular EXIF/meta data viewer tool for images) [EXIF data analysis report](http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fjanis.tokyo%2Fbike%2FIMG_0796.JPG) you will see: (I used the original image URL: `http://janis.tokyo/bike/IMG_0796.JPG`)

> Orientation:  Rotate 90 CW

Please pay attention to the **preview image** shown on the report page. Now, when you upload the image using SE's imgur interface, it extracts the Orientation attribute's value i.e. Rotate 90 CW from the EXIF data and *rotates* the image accordingly. You can see how the uploaded image looks like in rene's answer.

On the side note, I would also like to point out that imgur will ***strip*** the EXIF data once the image is uploaded to their server. You can see the [Metapicz report](http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FfGYeG.jpg) on the above uploaded image (`https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGYeGm.jpg`)

**Why does imgur strips the EXIF data?**

Here is a reply from imgur userecho question [Where is the EXIF data?](https://imgur.userecho.com/topic/42809-where-is-the-exif-data/) :

> This is one of the features of the service. exif data is removed
>   because the images are shared publicly and the developer does not want
>   hidden information to leak accidentally by users who might have no
>   idea what exif information is stored in the photos. I do not think
>   there is any setting available on imgur platform that retains the data
>   if you so desire.

Here is [reply](https://imgur.userecho.com/topic/60879-exif/) from Alan Schaaf (Founder of imgur):

> Sorry, but exif data is striped on purpose to keep the anonymity of
>   the uploader. This will not change.