# Is EXIF data removed from uploaded SE pictures?

Tags: discussion, support, images, uploader

Had a question in mind to post to Home Improvement when it got me to thinking about EXIF data. In most Stack Overflow questions where I would attach a picture, it would usually be a screen shot. However, in Home Improvement's case, I actually want to upload a camera picture.

If I upload this picture, is the EXIF data removed, or would viewers be able to retrieve the EXIF (and in turn GPS coordinates) data?

Comment: I think this says that it is removed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263502/recognize-exif-orientation-value-when-posting-images-and-or-allow-transform-in

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses **[imgur](http://imgur.com/)** for uploading and hosting the images. Imgur will ***strip*** the EXIF data once the image is uploaded to their server. Yes, GPS coordinates will also be *removed* as it relates to your identity. So, no worry of GPS coordinates of your house going online.

**Why does imgur strips the EXIF data?**

Here is a reply from imgur userecho question [Where is the EXIF data?](https://imgur.userecho.com/topic/42809-where-is-the-exif-data/) :

> This is one of the features of the service. exif data is removed
>   because the images are shared publicly and the developer does not want
>   hidden information to leak accidentally by users who might have no
>   idea what exif information is stored in the photos. I do not think
>   there is any setting available on imgur platform that retains the data
>   if you so desire.

Here is [reply](https://imgur.userecho.com/topic/60879-exif/) from Alan Schaaf (Founder of imgur):

> Sorry, but exif data is striped on purpose to keep the anonymity of
>   the uploader. This will not change.

Comment: Thanks! That makes me feel safer in posting a picture! :)

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be removed from StackExchange postings.  But more generally, if you want to upload a picture to any web site and want to be sure the EXIF data is not included, you can strip the EXIF data.  I use ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick:

```
gm convert image_with_exif.jpg image.ppm
gm convert image.ppm image_without_exif.jpg
or
convert image_with_exif.jpg image.ppm
convert image.ppm image_without_exif.jpg
```

with newer versions of ImageMagick (version 7.0.0-0 and later), use "magick" instead of "convert".

You can do it with one command

```
gm convert image_with_exif.jpg -strip image_without_exif.jpg
or
convert image_with_exif.jpg -strip image_without_exif.jpg
```

But then you have to trust ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick to strip it properly (it does, trust me, but don't sue me if it doesn't).