# Site-specific need for image uploader to paste EXIF exposure information into post along with image URL

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, images, uploader

*(This is a feature request following this Meta Photo-SE post: [Is there some way that we can help new users to add EXIF data to their photo?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7105/11924))*

At Photography Stack Exchange, when posters ask questions about their photos, we often have to ask them in comments to edit the question to include exposure information (shutter speed, aperture or f-number, ISO), and sometimes camera info (make/model, lens type, focal length). This is a constant dance we have to play with our new posters. Sometimes, the poster never edits the question, so either the answers are stuck speculating about the exposure conditions that could have caused their problems, or we're forced to close the question as unclear / needs details.

Rather than go back and forth with the "please edit and add exposure details" comments, **can the image uploader be modified to parse / return exposure information from the image's EXIF data if it exists?**

I realize this is a pretty narrow use-case, probably specific to Photo-SE only. I imagine this functionality would be undesirable for every other Stack. And I'm aware that Imgur is against returning or retaining EXIF data broadly and blanketly (ref: [Is EXIF data removed from uploaded SE pictures?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266391/175991)). But I imagine maybe a few possible approaches to the solution:

1. Negotiate a modification to the Imgur API to return a defined subset of EXIF data such as `ApertureValue`, `ShutterSpeedValue`, `ExposureCompensation`, `ISO`, `MeteringMode`, etc., but certainly no identifying information). Likely? No. But probably the best technical solution.
2. Pre-parse the EXIF information from a SE self-hosted CGI/script using whatever server-side EXIF library is available. This has the downside of requiring a temporary image upload to SE's servers just to get the EXIF data, but otherwise is unchanged with regards to the Imgur uploader process.
3. Use a 3rd-party EXIF parser service in parallel with the Imgur uploader. Something similar to https://exifinfo.org. This is similar to #2, but is dependent upon a separate service agreement, contract terms, etc. Probably the least desirable option.
4. Client-side solution. I'm not specifically familiar with Javascript-based EXIF parsers, but there seem to be a few, such as [exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js). I think this is probably the best solution. (*thank you @[nobody](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/906149/nobody) for this suggestion in the comments*)

Comment: On some sites, I've seen some images that fail to render correctly with EXIF data removed; they only look correct with the data intact. There's no way to upload those types of images to SE directly.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog I don't think we've ever had that kind of issue over at Photo-SE. Everything uploaded via the Imgur uploader renders correctly, and is devoid of EXIF.

Comment: While there currently exists no means to automatically extract and display the EXIF information of uploaded images on Stack Exchange sites it is possible for the uploader to manually add the "description of the image" to the ALT and add the "EXIF Data" to the Title area of the image; that would show the EXIF information on mouseover in the Tooltip. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271135/282094 and the Markdown Help. --- You could ask (possibly on Stack apps) for someone to create a UserScript for Photo.SE that uses a site to extract the EXIF and upload the image to stack.imgur ....

Comment: @Rob A custom UserScript is a great idea for regular posters, but I find that few of the Photo-SE regulars use Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey. Also, this doesn't solve the problem motivating this question, because new users by definition wouldn't know about UserScripts in the first place.

Comment: There's actually more than Photo.SE that holds photo competitions, and ***might*** want this implemented (or not): https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6885/90750 https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1422/72373  https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/716  https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1578/17365

Comment: There's precedents for site specific features. I almost wonder if a specific upload option that's not inline, with the option of ticking/unticking what tags you want might be an option, or just removing stuff like geotags. In theory, where a SO user is working/asking questions on image processing, it might be useful too :D

Comment: Your feature request wpuld benefit from listing already available third party tools that could be implemented as a solution to your request.

Comment: @Journeyman The Photo, Travel, Outdoors, and Drones sites might want the option of including GeoTags from the EXIF, frequently that is why people enable the GPS to record the exact location of the photo; and provide a link to a map - people photographing in their home are unlikely to want such a feature, and that's why it must be made abundantly clear exactly what information will be available (further cluttering and complicating the UI). --- Indeed the Cooking.SE would benefit from [imagemaps](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp) so you could rollover the food for recipes.

Comment: *"Pre-parse the EXIF information from a SE self-hosted CGI/script using whatever server-side EXIF library is available."* - I guess that could be done client side too?

Comment: @Rob re: uploader interface would have to really spell out the details: partially yes, partially no. It should link to the MSE page announcing the feature, where all of the details are specifically spelled out. But I'm not asking to keep certainly EXIF data embedded in the image; I'm asking to have certain non-identifiable tags pasted as Markdown text in the user's post along with the image link & URL Markdown. If a person wants to remove, edit, or format that pasted data, it's visible to them while they're editing.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm not familiar with any 3rd party sites that might be appropriate to partner with, only because I have no idea of SE Network's business partnering process or what they would require. But for example, in the original discussion at Meta Photo-SE, https://exifinfo.org was a suggested example.

Comment: @nobody That's an excellent idea, didn't occur to me.

Comment: [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360895/site-specific-need-for-image-uploader-to-paste-exif-exposure-information-into-po?noredirect=1#comment1204312_360895), that's [what it says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360895/site-specific-need-for-image-uploader-to-paste-exif-exposure-information-into-po?noredirect=1#comment1204261_360895) in my first comment. Based on the [views and votes on Photo.meta.SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7105/37074) I think you've came to MSE **5 weeks too early** to say that "people on your site want this". It will be unaffordable.

Comment: @Rob I don't understand, why is this 5 weeks too early.

Comment: @Rob I hear you, and I appreciate your inputs. But none of those are my concern to solve. Our site is getting declining participation. Long term high-rep users have left. These days, several blatantly off-topic questions that should have been closed can't even get 5 close votes because of decreased participation in the review queues. So when a regular asks for a possible feature that would objectively remove friction with new users, and possibly increase retention of some new posters, I'm faced with a choice: do I wait until (probably never) to get some number of votes on the meta question,

Comment: and become just another example of how nothing is improving and nobody is being listened to; Or, do I come to Meta-SE and raise that feature request up the flagpole and try to advocate for my site's needs? That's what brought me here, now. I don't think we'll get a lot of people who "want" this, because they generally won't use it themselves. They want it on behalf of the 1st time posters, to make the first experience on Photo-SE better, and better for the regulars when having to first interact with the 1st time posters.

Comment: @scottbb - I wouldn't get too discouraged by meta comments outside staff saying something is unlikely, it's a tough crowd.and if we don't speak up about problems we face no one will know, whether they are fixed on the short term or not.  I personally think, as a mod on meta it's something valuable to voice out. I wouldn't status review tag it now, but it's very something I hope the company considers

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks. But I’m not discouraged at all. I don’t really expect this to be implemented, because it’s a fairly low-need case for a specific site (or few). It’s just a feature request. I do software dev myself, so I know every feature has a time/cost/benefit tradeoff. But thanks for the kind words. =)