# Image orientation sometimes changes between the preview and the actual uploaded image

Tags: bug, images, uploader

The image orientation sometimes changes between the preview and the actual uploaded image. It probably has to do with the EXIF data, but I believe the preview should match more closely the final output.

[image]

[file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4y6Mj_UZoTESVgxRUJRY1I1TGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have answered a similar issue [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263503/158100) but I woud expect based on my own answer that imgur should rotate the image. Strange.

Comment: @rene they do with the original, but not in the thumbnails. Probably. Most likely.

Comment: the thumbnail is rendered entirely client-side by the browser via `URL.createObjectURL(file)`, so that's how the browser actually renders the raw image, before it's uploaded to imgur. It seems to be imgur that does the rotation.