# Where is the "provide a link from the web" for image uploads gone?

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

Previously, I could give links to images on the web and they would be uploaded as shown in the old UI screenshots in this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/200117

However as of 2018-11-8, the link from "You can also provide a link from the web" part is gone:

[image]

Is there some workaround? That was a very good feature.

Chromium 70 Ubuntu 18.04.